# Using Build.SourceVersionMessage with ' and " in DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, devops, pipeline

In a azure DevOps pipeline I would like to use the Build.SourceVersionMessage variable as the releaseNotes in a NuGet.nuspec file I use to publish my artifact.

In the NuGet.nuspec I have this line <releaseNotes>$release_notes$</releaseNotes>.

I found that I need to escape the xml characters by using a powershell script like this.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
   displayName: 'Modify NuGet.nuspec with release notes'
   inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
       # I can not find a way to pass a value with semicolons via the -Properties to nuget pack. Therefor we modify the NuGet.nuspec file directly.
       $escapedMsg = [System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape("$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)")
       Write-Host "Escaped release notes: $escapedMsg"
       (Get-Content "NuGet.nuspec") -replace '\$release_notes\$', $escapedMsg | Set-Content "NuGet.nuspec"
```

However this script still has problems in case the message contains double quotes.  The powershell script fails because the string inside the Escape(...) is malformed.

Then I could use single quotes in the script but then it will not work in case the message has single quotes.

Is the any way to get a SourceVersionMessage with any characters into the NuGet.nuspec file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is a very simple solution.
Instead of using $(Build.SourceVersionMessage) that is being replaced before the powershell script is executed. I can use the environment variable BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE.
Like this:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
   displayName: 'Modify NuGet.nuspec with release notes'
   inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
       $escapedMsg = [System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape($env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)
       Write-Host "Escaped release notes: $escapedMsg"
       (Get-Content "NuGet.nuspec") -replace '\$release_notes\$', $escapedMsg | Set-Content "NuGet.nuspec"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is the any way to get a SourceVersionMessage with any characters into the NuGet.nuspec file ?

I suggest that we can use the Replace Tokens task from the [Replace Tokens Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

Here are the steps:

Step1: Set the #{varname}# (e.g. `#{Build.SourceVersionMessage}#` ) in the NuGet.nuspec file.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata minClientVersion="3.3.0">
    <id>ContentFilesExample</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>nuget</authors>
    <owners>nuget</owners>
    <releaseNotes>#{Build.SourceVersionMessage}#</releaseNotes>
    ....
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Step2:The variable `$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)` will automatically replace the placeholder character in the  NuGet.nuspec when using the Replace tokens task.

```
- task: replacetokens@6
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    root: filepath
    sources: NuGet.nuspec
```

In this case, all special characters will be part of the variable value(string type). We don't need to translate special characters when using this method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I guess this would also work, however I found another solution that works better for me, because my script is part of a build template that is used by many build pipelines. So changing  the NuGet.nuspec is not so easy. This could of cause also have be fixed but the other solution is simpler.